# Get traced code lines while debugging in visual studio for c#

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to know, is it possible to get the lines of code which are touched or covered while debugging in visual studio for c# application.

Let me explain.

I have class called Bank.
In that class there are 4 methods called
1. Deposit ()
2. Withdraw ()
3. Check balance()
4. DoEverything() which basically calls the methods 1,2,3 one after the other sequentially.

Let's hope for now, All the first 3 methods are independent, ie they won't call other methods.

The application starts with asking for a user input, basically a method number, what he wants to do. Then it calls that method and done.

Now I wanted to know, is it possible in visual studio or any other tool, to know which portion of souce code is touched for a particular input.

Basically I am looking for all the code line which are touched for that particular input.

Comment: I agree with Sergey's suggestion, you could use the Runtime Flow tool in your side. Is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to see all methods and classes involved in processing a certain input.